# Representation of $xyz$-equation

Tags: linear-algebra

Why does a form of the following equation represent a plane,

$ax+by+cz=d$, where $x$, $y$ and $z$ are the axes.

Also, when solving a system of equations, why does eliminating a variable work?

Comment: You have two rather different questions here, the second of which is rather too vague - eliminating a variable, if you can do it, is a potential way of simplifying the situation. For the first, what do you mean by a plane? The definition matters because that will tell us what needs to be said to explain the answer.

Comment: A geometric plane, like a flat square or rectangle. I cant post a picture, but if you search for math plane you will exactly see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

One possible answer:

You can write the equation
in the form

$(X-P)\cdot Q = 0$

where $X$ is any point
satisfying the equation
and $P$ and $Q$ are vectors.

This means that
the set of points
satisfying the equation
are those such that
the line though any point in the set
and a fixed point ($P$)
is perpendicular to a fixed vector
($Q$).

To me,
that means that the set of points
lie in a plane.

Comment: And if you want to define the plane by two (non-concurrent) vectors, $V$, $W$ representing distinct lines lying in the plane you can take $Q= V\times W$ the cross product, which is perpendicular to the plane.

Answer (score 0):

For the second question (eliminating variables):

When we have a system of equations in two or more variables, the goal is to find the values of those variables. Then, when resubstituing the values of the variables into the original equations, hold true.

An easy example:

$$
\begin{matrix}
x + y = 8 \\
3x - 5y = 8 \\
\\
\end{matrix}
$$

We can multiply the first equation by $5$ to get

$$
\begin{matrix}
5x + 5y = 40 \\
3x - 5y = 8 \\
\\
\end{matrix}
$$

then adding to get $$8x = 48$$ or $$x=6.$$

Going back to the first equation and substituting gives us $$y = 2.$$

We can check to see that $x = 6, y = 2$ is correct by subsituting them into the second equation to get $$3(6) - 5(2) = 18 - 10 = 8.$$

There are times when eliminating a variable will either give no solutions or infinite solutions.

No solutions: 
$$
\begin{matrix}
3x + y = 6 \\
3x + y = 4 \\
\\
\end{matrix}
$$

If we subtracted both equations, we would get $0 = 2$, which is nonsense.

Infinite solutions:

$$
\begin{matrix}
4x + 2y = 12 \\
2x + y = 6 \\
\\
\end{matrix}
$$

If you either double the second equation or halved the first, you get the same equation (actually, parallel lines).  Then the equation would be $y = 6 - 2x$ for all $x$.